# Why can't I scan the label I received from the printer with the barcode reader?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, barcode, barcode-scanner

I create a barcode with the value entered in the Winforms application and print it with the printer. Afterwards, when I want to scan it with a barcode reader, I cannot scan it.
This is my code:

```
private void GenerateBarcodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum.Draw(textBox1.Text, 50, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the barcode number you want to generate.");
    }
}
public void PrintPicture(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    // bmp.SetResolution(203, 203);
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 20, 20, new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument pDoc = new PrintDocument();
    pDoc.PrintPage += PrintPicture;
    pd.Document = pDoc;
    if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pDoc.Print();
    }
}
```

The printer model I use for printing is Godex G300. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you scan it from the screen before printing?

Comment: Yes i can with the iphone app from screen. But barcode scanner can not scan it from screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the DPI. I added this line to the code.

`bmp.SetResolution(203, 203);`

This is the new method:

```
        private void PrintPicture(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            bmp.SetResolution(203, 203);
            pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 38, 10);
            bmp.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one major issue in your code, refer to [this Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to understand how exactly it's done.

When you assign an event handler for `PrintPage()`, you should wrap it inside a `PrintPageEventHandler` like this:

```
pDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler (this.PrintPicture);
```

Try doing the above and if it doesn't work, debug it by putting an actual breakpoint inside the `PrintPicture()` method.

Comment: That hasn't been necessary since C# 2.0 when method group conversion was introduced.

Comment: This is not the solution.